PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the Doctrine Proxy directory on SuiteCRM clean installation
i had a problem with a dockerized SuiteCRM 8.6 fresh installation that return everytime i try to rebuild the cache from user interface:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the Doctrine Proxy directory "/bitnami/suitecrm/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies".

After too many days of testing i realized that the problem seems to be related to a incompatibility between SuiteCRM (Symphony) and Docker's bind mount.
I have tested in different ways:

Permissions and file ownership are double-checked. Keep in mind that cache rebuilding from UI is started by apache user (www-data), and file ownership and group is www-data:www-data.

The problem is present everytime i work with docker's bind mount, but strangely works perfectly if i try with bitnami official release without bind mount. If i set bind mount in this installation, the problem occurs again.


I have asked for help on Official Support Forum here and GitHub with no luck.
Anyone have an idea about how solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.
Edit, i give you some extra information.
My Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:24.04

ARG USER_ID=1000

ENV TZ=Europe/Rome
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install vim -y
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get install apache2 -y

RUN apt -y install ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2 libapache2-mod-php8.2
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2-fpm libapache2-mod-fcgid
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2-mysql
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2-curl php8.2-intl php8.2-zip php8.2-imap php8.2-gd
RUN apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils php-ldap php8.2-ldap php8.2-soap
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2-xdebug
RUN apt install -y php8.2-xml php8.2-mbstring
RUN apt install -y zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gnupg \
    g++ \
    procps \
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libicu-dev  \
    libonig-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    acl \
    && echo 'alias sf="php bin/console"' >> ~/.bashrc


RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enconf php8.2-fpm


RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    npm

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install --global yarn

RUN usermod -u ${USER_ID} www-data

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer


CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 9000

My docker-compose.yml
services:
  suitecrm:
    container_name: suitecrm-mca
    build: .
    networks:
      - suitecrm_net
    volumes:
      #SuiteCRM Application Folder
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
      #PHP config
      - ./docker/config/php/php.ini:/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
      - ./docker/config/php/php.ini:/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
      #APACHE config
      - ./docker/config/apache/sites.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sites.conf
      #APACHE Log Folder
      - ./logs/apache:/var/log/apache2/
      #PHP Log Folder
      - ./logs/php:/var/log/php/
      #PHP Log Folder
      - ./logs/xdebug:/tmp/
      #XDebug settings
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql-mca
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=suitecrm
      - MYSQL_USER=suitecrm
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=suitecrm
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=suitecrm
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    networks:
      - suitecrm_net
networks:
    suitecrm_net:
        driver: bridge


If you think it's related to docker, you should include some of those docker setup details. Is your bind mount readonly? https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ What are the permissions in the original directory? Do the uids map to the same value? If you do a test chmod 777 does it work then?

Hi @rand'Chris , thank for your questions.
Yeah, i think that is related to Docker, because the bitnami image from scratch works perfectly, and the problem begin only when i use the bind mounts.
My bind mount is bidirectional and i have already tried with RUN usermod -u ${USER_ID} www-data (when USER_ID also tried with id 1000, 33, and 501) with no luck. Chmod 777 didn't help.  I edit the question with the extra information you asked.

Solution is “to esclude” /cache folder from docker-compose.yml bind mount like below:
services:
  suitecrm:
    container_name: suitecrm
    build: .
    volumes:
      #SuiteCRM Application Folder
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
      - /var/www/html/cache/   #Anonymous volume inside the existing one

In this way cache subfolder can re-create proxy classes on rebuild and repair.
Thanks.
